# Solution Verification in change from rectangular to spherical coordinates of an improper triple integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, improper-integrals, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

I was doing the next integral and I have some questions about to solve it:

$$\int\int\int_{S}\frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{2}}dV$$
where S is determined by $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\geq1$ this implies that we are integrating outside the unit sphere. Whith this we can find out quickly the limits of integration: $1\leq x,y,z\leq\infty$, then:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{2}}dxdydz$$

In this case I'll use spherical coordinates because I think is a little more easy reduce the expression, so the integration limits in my point of view are:
$0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ and $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$ for the angles, because is technically all the sphere the integration volume, but the radius will be $1\leq r\leq\infty$, the reason is we are outside of the unitary sphere. Applying it, using the differential changes and solving we have:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{r^{2}\sin\phi}{(r^{2})^{2}}d\theta d\phi dr=\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin\phi}{r^{2}}d\theta d\phi dr=4\pi$$

My problem begins when I've put the integral in cartesian coordinates in Wolfram Alpha, the result is 0.329662 and there is not procedure, only that number. Why is that result? Where is my mistake? Is Actually more easy use in this case rectangular or cylindrical form?

Thank u for reading, I hope u have a good day :D

Comment: With $x,y,z \ge 1$, you only cover a *part* of the region outside of the unit sphere!

Comment: So what region of integration am I covering? I thought it was absolutely everything that was outside the ball, including its border, and  why is only a part? (Edit: Is the first octant only?)

Comment: Yes, you cover only a part of the positive octant, and it's not even the whole part of the first octant which lies outside the unit sphere. (For example, the point $(2,1/2,1/2)$ lies in the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 1$, but is not included in your integral.)

Comment: Finally after some days I've understood that haha, I was thinking the limits of the second were wrong but the problem is in my attempt in cartesian coords, So I decided to use in this case only the spherical form cuz I think it's too complicated try to use that form. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big deal, but I just want to write some of my observations. This is an hell of an integral. If we make a change of variables, $x\rightarrow x+1, y\rightarrow y+1, z\rightarrow z+1$ then the integral becomes
$$I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{((x+1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+1)^2)^2}dxdydz$$
and in spherical coordinates
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r^2\sin\phi}{(r^2+2(\cos\theta\sin\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi+\cos\phi)r+3)^2}dr d\theta d\phi.$$
If we approximate the "denominator" of the integrand by half angles, $\theta\approx\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\phi\approx\frac{\pi}{4}$ then
$$I\approx \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r^2}{(r^2+(2+\sqrt{2})r+3)^2}dr\approx 0.305$$

Comment: That change of coordinates was to avoid the sphere of radius 1 and integrate in that region. Am I correct? That was a very good idea!

Comment: Translation....